# How to prevent GAE from throwing ERROR 502?

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml, app.yaml

For my case, this is error is caused because my my app is taking a long time to send the response. I just want to know what parameters should I add to my `app.yaml` file so that the `deadline`changes from 30 sec to something like 120 sec.

My `app.yaml` code

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT app:app

runtime_config:
    python_version: 3

resources:
    cpu: 4
    memory_gb: 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to official documentation, App Engine Standard is optimized for applications with short-lived requests, **a few hundred milliseconds**.

However a request can take as long as 60 seconds to respond. After this time period the request handler will be interupted.

[How Requests are Handled](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-handled).

> An app that doesn't will not scale well with App Engine's
> infrastructure.

I would recomend to use [Google Stackdriver Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/) to find the reasons why your application requests execution time is greater than 60  seconds.

## EDIT

The answer provided was for Google App Engine Standard. I noticed that you are using Google App Engine Flex. The 60 seconds limit does not apply to Google App Engine Flex because

> Application instances run within Docker containers on Compute Engine
> virtual machines (VM).

App Engine Flex is recommended for:

> Applications that receive consistent traffic, experience regular
> traffic fluctuations, or meet the parameters for scaling up and down
> gradually.

[Choosing an App Engine environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments)

The 30 seconds error timeout might be a gunicorn server timeout.

Change your app.yaml, adding `-t 120` (timeout 120 seconds):

```
      runtime: python
      env: flex 
      entrypoint: gunicorn -t 120 -b :$PORT main:app
```

Here you can find a related SO question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50667822/increase-time-to-run-code-for-google-flexible-app-engine-delaying-deadlineexceed/50686002).

Comment: I have checked the logs. The response is taking a lot more time depending on the user entry. Apparently, I am scraping a website in my back-end, so depending on the user input, multiple such pages are getting scraped. I can not reduce my scraping time any further. First, my app is taking somewhat 45 sec for response, but my app show 502 error at around 30 sec. I just want to know is there any way of increasing the time allowed by App Engine?